# jQuery Popbox issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have template which contain a button. When you click on this button, a pop up box will appear.

The problem I'm facing is: I can't find a way to move the button and the popbox to the middle and approach the code. If I click close on the popbox, the popbox will close.

Here the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FK9TY/
[image]
Can someone kindly help me?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">


    .Richard  {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FF58C3;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}



</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#ClickMe").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            /*if (.attr("data-display") == "visible") {

            };*/
            $("#moveableBox").fadeToggle();
        });
        $( "#moveableBox" ).draggable({ handle: "#moveBox" });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="ClickMe">Click Me</button>

<div id="moveableBox" data-display="hidden" class="Richard">
<div id="moveBox">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting how you're calling `"moveBox"` actually an element that contains the text `close` but any way you expect it to `drag` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what you were looking for?  adding `margin:auto;` to `.Box` `CSS` [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/FK9TY/4/)

Comment: Great pumpkinpro thank you but do you know how to close the popbox if you click close?

Comment: Pumpkinson how do u remove the button?

Comment: `$('#moveBox').click(function(){$(this).parent().hide()});`